# Integrate $F'(x)=f(x)$ in the FTC

Tags: calculus

From the fundamental theorem of calculus we have
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_a^x f(t) \, dt \tag 1\\
\frac{dF(x)}{dx}&=f(x) \tag 2
\end{align}
If I integrate equation (2) I get
\begin{align}
\int_a^xdF&=\int_a^xf(t) \, dt \iff \\
F(x)-F(a)&=\int_a^xf(t) \, dt \iff \\
F(x)&=F(a)+\int_a^xf(t)\, dt \tag 3
\end{align}
But (3) isn't the same as equation (1), shouldn't it be that?

Comment: $F(a)=0$, so there's no contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Since $F(x)$ is defined as a definite integral starting at $a$, then we have that $F(a)=0$, so there's no problem.

By definition,

$$F(a)=\int_a^a f(t)\,dt = 0$$

Does that help?